# StackOverflowError while traversing a binary search tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a method that returns the deepest node in a BST. I have this code which raises a StackOverflow error:

```
public int getDeepestNode(AvlNode head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (Math.max(getDeepestNode(head.getLeftNode()), getDeepestNode(head.getRightNode())) + 1);
    }
}
```

To me it looks fine, why is it raising the error?

Comment: Your BST most likely has a loop, i.e. one of the *left* or *right* nodes points back to a node higher in the tree. Or then your tree is very poorly balanced and very deep.

Comment: @Codo ...or one of the other methods has a problem in it. They should also be posted, i.e. `getLeftNode()` and `getRightNode()`.

Comment: You should first make at least a rudimentary check to see what your tree is traversing.  Insert a trivial print statement at the top of the routine to trace execution: **print head**.  It might be easier to read if you print its value.  This will let you see easily enough whether you've found a loop in your tree, a lack of proper recursion in your code, or perhaps some other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDeepestNode must occur repeatedly on the stack.

More than likely you have a cycle in the AVL tree. The naming, `head`, already might be an indication of unclean thoughts. Debugging helps.
Alternatively, you might harden your code as:

```
public int getDeepestNode(AvlNode head) {
    return getDeepestNodeSafe(head, new ArrayList<AvlNode>());
}

public int getDeepestNodeSafe(AvlNode head, List<AvlNode> pathFromRoot) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (pathFromRoot.contains(head)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Cycle: ");
            for (AvlNode node : pathFromRoot) {
                if (node == head) {
                   sb.append("***");
                }
                sb.append(node).append("; ");
            }
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARN, sb.toString());
            return 0;
        }
        pathFromRoot.add(head);
        int depth = Math.max(getDeepestNodeSafe(head.left, pathFromRoot),
                             getDeepestNodeSafe(head.right), pathFromRoot) + 1;
        pathFromRoot.remove(pathFromRoot.size() - 1); // Undo
        return depth;
    }
}
```

Throwing an **IllegalStateException** would definitely be better, but with this code you might find the error faster (or not).